# Transfering of files from Windows hangs randomly

Tags: files, transfer

I have a 40 GB folder to transfer (some backup files from Windoze machine), but it stops randomly. The other folder with 2 GB of data transferred ok, just not the big one. I'm running Truecrypt on Windows, but that isn't the case as I've tried transferring from a not encrypted source. Same thing happens, just hangs.

Used latest 13.04 w/Samba, tried it on Mint, different CAT cables etc. -- same thing.

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It could be Windows, it could be the encryption, it could be a whole host of things. I'm a practical person so for one-off issues, there's rarely a point in looking for the root of the problem... That could take weeks of painful debugging and even then it could culminate in nothing.

No, I would try the following options in this order:

1. Create a writable share on your Ubuntu machine and "push" the files from Windows.
2. Use a FTP server on Ubuntu (fairly simple, running `twistd -n ftptwistd` will open a FTP server on port `2121` - but you can install more industrious servers if you want) and push from Windows.
3. Reverse #2, and run an FTP or HTTP (`python -m SimpleHTTPServer` if you have python on the Windows box) server on Windows and pull the files over from Ubuntu.
4. External storage.

Comment: Oli, I know I could just ftp/scp (I haven't treid it yet). Thought that file transfer should work out of the box. Yes, it could be encryption, but as I mentioned, transferring from unencrypted source produces same results.Pushing files from Windows to Ubuntu creates another culprit -- speed, I only get 3,2MB/s while getting files from Windows 9,3MB/s.

Will try your method and report.

Thanks!

Comment: @MikeE It likely does work for most people but there are situations that are buggier than others and you're likely running into one of those. By all means report the issue on Launchpad but it's probably not going to get you moving files around any time soon (given there are reports of things like this going back to 2007 and beyond). FTP and HTTP are more stable protocols for this, and should support resume if things do halt.

Comment: Thanks again! Eventually all roads lead to Rome. Will try ftp if it fails, I'll decrypt all drives and see what happens.